# How to find implicitly generated indexes on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Is there any way to detect if an index was generated automatically by the DBMS when adding, 
e.g. the primary key or a unique constraint?

At the moment I try to fetch all the indexes of an table by using jdbc metadata. But the result here contains also the implizit generated indexes. I need now the possibility to detect if a dedicated index was auto-generated or not.

I've already tried to get these information from tables like pg_class or pg_index. But no success.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to distinguish those indexes - after all there is no difference between an index created automatically and one that was created manually.

The only way I can think of is to stick to some naming convention for your "manual" indexes. Then you could filter out all those that do not comply with that naming convention.

Comment: Yes i also have this feeling. What i'm currently trying is to filter out the indexes that have the same name as a constraint in the pg_constraint table. But i don't know if it is guaranteed that the names are identical...

Comment: @Michael: if you manually create a e.g. unique constraint without naming it (`alter table foo add unique(bar)`), you'll get the same situation. So it's not 100% reliable either.

Comment: (DAT NAME ^^) .... also the scenarion you described seems to work with the approach i described. I'm using the following statement now:   
`SELECT *
  FROM pg_class
 WHERE 
 oid IN (
    SELECT indexrelid
      FROM pg_index, pg_class
     WHERE pg_class.relname='xxx'
       AND pg_class.oid=pg_index.indrelid)
 AND pg_class.relname not in (
  select conname from pg_constraint
     );`